# Receiving and using a console input while connected to server

Tags: java, string, sockets, client, java.util.scanner

I have used both a reader object and a scanner but while this client is connected to a simple socket server and they are both running, I cannot take an input from the user in the console and pass it to the server. pressing enter simply skips a line, scanner.nextLine() seems to capture nothing or something is going wrong when passing a variable to the output streamer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;  
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message;

    String host = "macbook";
    int port = 9999;

    //attempts to connect to given host and port
    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));           
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + host +".");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + host+".");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // if everything has been initialized then write some data
    if (socket != null && outputStream != null && reader != null) {
        try {
            message=scan.nextLine();

            outputStream.writeBytes(message);    
            String responseLine;
            while ((responseLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
                if (responseLine.indexOf("Ok") != -1) {
                  break;
                }
            }
            //closes client once communication with server has ended
            outputStream.close();
            reader.close();
            socket.close();   
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }
}           
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're unsure if the line is read from the console; have you verified it isn't?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The line is not being read from the console. I added a print statement right after to double check, nothing.